# Is there any low level network library for Internet protocol suite?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, ip, data-link-layer

Is there any low level network library for Internet protocol suite?

A library for capturing and sending `Ethernet frames` (Link layer), handling `IP` and `ICMP` packets (Internet layer), Transport layer and so on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Answer (score 1):

Using netfilter in linux, you can create rule for INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD. You can also use -j QUEUE to send specific rule chain to the QUEUE. Then you may use libnetqueue_filter library to read the packets from queue and take necessary action. e.g. ACCEPT, or DROP them.

In windows, however, this task is not easy. WinPcap only send a copy of the packets to you. It means you cannot decide what to do with the incoming traffic (drop, accept, or queue them). You may want to use the winDivert, or WinPkFilter to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows check out [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) or for Linux the [Netfilter project](http://www.netfilter.org/index.html).